# Can I get receiver information from AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest

I want to know from java code that if my receiver class is registered to app's AndroidManifest.xml
(I'm library developer, not app)

```
<receiver android:name="some class..." >
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY" /> 
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE" /> 
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED" /> 
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve it by call PackageManager's getReceiverInfo method, the code below is invoked in a activity

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
ActivityInfo receiverInfo = packageManager.getReceiverInfo(new ComponentName(this, ReceiverName.class), 0);
```